# Not able to access jboss 7 admin console on AWS EC2 Linux Env

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jboss, jboss7.x

I am not able to access the jboss console via the {public IP/DNS}:{Mgmt-Port} from my machine?
The Jboss is running inside the amazon linux (one of the EC2 instance in AWS).

I have used bind addresses as `0.0.0.0` but still not able to connect to admin console with the public ip and the management port, the ports are already opened in AWS console to accept the incoming traffic.

Anyone have any thoughts on what should be done?

I used:

```
ssh i [PEM FILE PATH] -L 9992:0.0.0.0:9990 [EC2 username]@EC2address.com
```

and was able to connect to jboss admin console with:

http://localhost:9992/console/

But i want to connect to the admin console with my public ip and management port.

Process of jboss startup:

```
./standalone.sh -Djboss.bind.addres=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /home/jboss/jboss

  JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

=========================================================================

23:19:15,458 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
23:19:15,729 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
23:19:15,789 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
23:19:16,893 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
23:19:16,912 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
23:19:16,916 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
23:19:16,943 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
23:19:17,005 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
23:19:17,010 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
23:19:17,043 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
23:19:17,083 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
23:19:17,096 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
23:19:17,147 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
23:19:17,164 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
23:19:17,192 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
23:19:17,235 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
23:19:17,262 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
23:19:17,263 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
23:19:17,521 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
23:19:17,670 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
23:19:18,163 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-2) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080
23:19:18,424 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017100: Listening on /0.0.0.0:9999
23:19:18,499 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /home/jboss/jboss/standalone/deployments
23:19:18,540 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:4447
23:19:18,608 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
23:19:18,652 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://0.0.0.0:9990
23:19:18,652 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 3519ms - Started 133 of 208 services (74 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: Hello, I'm experiencing exactly the same problem. Did you resolve it and if so how? TIA

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and put

```
ssh -i [PEM FILE PATH] -L 9992:127.0.0.1:9990 [EC2 username]@[EC2 Public ip address]
```

and then you can open url 'http://127.0.0.1:9992' in safari.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. To resolve the issue I did two things

1. started the server using the following command. You can use nohup/service/systemctl to execute the process in the background/service

   either use

   - ./standalone.sh -b=0.0.0.0 -bmanagement=0.0.0.0
     or  use
   - ./standalone.sh -Djboss.bind.address=0.0.0.0 -Djboss.bind.address.management=0.0.0.0
     [in your command one 's' was missing in 'address']

     - For more details ref: http://blog.arungupta.me/bind-wildfly-different-ip-address-multihomed/
2. I edited the AWS security group's inbound rules to allow access from any IP address as given in the image. [ I used it for test purpose.] You may use more stringent inbound rules to restrict access.

[Edit AWS Security Group's inbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhL17.png)